# How to give a vertex a value other than int in a boost graph

Tags: c++, boost, graph, struct

I am currently trying to create a graph where a vertex is a struct shown below. I'm wondering how to do this specifically but also how to give a vertex any value other than int.  My code is below and gives the error "no instance of overloaded function "add_edge" matches the argument list"

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;


struct Node{
    int position;
    string arrow;

};
int main()
{

    Node m,p,q;

    typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int> EdgeWeightProperty;
    typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeWeightProperty > DirectedGraph;
    typedef boost::graph_traits<DirectedGraph>::edge_iterator edge_iterator;

    DirectedGraph g;
    add_edge(m, p, 8, g);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You will have to encode the vertex payload in the type of the graph, I'm afraid. Have you checked the examples and documentation at Boost's and looked at the meaning of the various template parameters?

Comment: Reading examples and the documentation definitely help. [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/007dcd4d19c0335b).